# Android button permanently on bottom

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have the following Xml code where I want to display the content of a fragment into FrameLayount but I don't know how to keep my button always on bottom.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_lista_preguntas"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.ingenierovagabundo.encuestafacil.GUI.ListaPreguntasActivity">

<!-- Toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar_nueva_pregunta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contenedor_Pregunta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/npa_button_guardar"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `FrameLayout`. This will expand the `FrameLayout` to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Which should result the Button to be at the bottom. 
So your resulting FrameLayout will be,

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contenedor_Pregunta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">

</FrameLayout>
```

For more on `layout_weight` follow the link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Answer (score 1):

you can use RelativeLayout insted of LinearLayout as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_lista_preguntas"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.ingenierovagabundo.encuestafacil.GUI.ListaPreguntasActivity">

<!-- Toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbar_nueva_pregunta"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contenedor_Pregunta"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar_nueva_pregunta">

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:text="@string/npa_button_guardar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a `LinearLayout` as container, then the elements follow each other.

If you want to keep your button always on bottom, use a `RelativeLayout` with 
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

You also need to close your container! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code in activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorOrange"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
            tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in content_main.xml, use this Code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```